Newton's Laws: Inclined Plane
The question asks "What is the force required to balance m1 on an inclined plane." The question also states that there is no friction between m1 and ground and m1 and m2. What is the force required to balance it.
.

The force required is $m_1 g  \tan \theta$ . The component of $m_1g$ along the inclined plane is $m_1 g \sin \theta$. The component of $F$ along the inclined plane is $F \cos \theta$. So,
$$ F= m_1 \times g \times {\frac {\sin \theta }{\cos \theta}},$$
which equals, $F =m_1 g \tan \theta$, provided $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity at that place acting vertically downwards.
Edit:- $m_2$ has no component acting on the other block, nor is there a question of friction. So, the second block, has practically no effect on the first block, except giving an inclined plane. So, it has no relationship with the force.
Hope that helps.

Shouldn't the answer be m1gtanθ. Me and my friend are confused onto why m2 doesn't affect the force applied to balance the object on m2.

what does "along the inclined plane" mean? Its that $\vec F \cdot \hat n$...why can't we just use "horizontal" and "vertical" components?

@CuriousAvenger have given an appropriate edit. Please upvote and accept if it helps.
